# Can I track visits to a Google Drive file with Google Analytics?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics

My university's website profile of me has a link to my CV, which is hosted on Google Drive (on my personal account, over which I have ownership).

I would like to track visits to my CV with Google Analytics, and get a rough idea of from where visitors to my CV are coming.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What format do you use for your resume?   A Google document?  An uploaded word document?   A HTML document? A PDF?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics runs in JS. Can you host this reliably in Google Drive?

If it's merely the link clicks that you wish to track, use bit.ly as a link shortener and add that shortned link on the site.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is the following:

1. You can create a one-page blog on Blogger.
2. Add your well-formatted resume to the HTML page.
3. Copy your PDF to Google Drive and share it properly.
4. Add a `printer friendly version` link to the top of your page and link it to your Google Drive.
5. Configure Google Analytics properly
6. Finally add the Google Analytics related JS to your HTML page.

Then you can enjoy the result and track your visitors.